# Record shellcheck findings in Jenkins

Tags: shell, jenkins, shellcheck

I'm looking for a way to record violation findings of [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) in my Jenkins Pipeline script. I was not able to find something so far. For other tools (Java, Python), I'm using [Warnings Next Generation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/warnings-ng-plugin), but it does not seem to support shellcheck, yet. I'd like to have the violations visualized within my Jenkins Job dashboard. Does anyone have experience with that? Or perhaps a ready to use custom tool for Warnings NG?

Comment: I seem to recall ShellCheck being able to output a Checkstyle report, and Jenkins being able to parse that (perhaps with a plugin).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did find a feasible solution myself. Like suggested in the comments, spellcheck offers checkstyle format, which can be parsed and visualized with Warnings NG. The following Pipeline stage definition works fine.

```
stage('Analyze') {
    steps {
        catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS') {
            sh """#!/bin/bash
                # The null command `:` only returns exit code 0 to ensure following task executions.
                shellcheck -f checkstyle *.sh > shellcheck.xml || :
            """
            recordIssues(tools: [checkStyle(pattern: 'shellcheck.xml')])
        }
    }
}
```

Running the build generates a nice trend diagram like follows.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Running shellcheck for all files merging the output in a single xml file didn't play well with recordIssues in my case.

I had create individual report for each source file to make it work.

```
stage('Shellcheck') {
  steps {
    catchError(
        buildResult: hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS.toString(),
        stageResult: hudson.model.Result.UNSTABLE.toString(),
        message: "shellcheck error detected, but allowing job to continue!")
    {
      sh '''
        # shellcheck with all files in single xml doesnt play well with jenkins report
        ret=0
        for file in $(grep -rl '^#!/.*/bash' src); do
          echo shellcheck ${file}
          mkdir -p .checkstyle/${file}/
          shellcheck -f checkstyle ${file} > .checkstyle/${file}/shellcheck.xml || (( ret+=$? ))
        done
        exit ${ret}
      '''
    }//catchError
  }//steps
  post {
    always {
      recordIssues(tools: [checkStyle(pattern: '.checkstyle/**/shellcheck.xml')])
    }
  }//post
}//stage
```